# What regex in java can capture and remove this pattern?

Tags: java, regex

Suppose I have a few lines out of wikipedia XML that looks like this:

> [[Image:ChicagoAnarchists.jpg|thumb|A sympathetic engraving by
>   [[Walter Crane]] of the executed "Anarchists of Chicago" after the
>   [[Haymarket affair]]. The Haymarket affair is generally considered the
>   most significant event for the origin of international [[May Day]]
>   observances]] In 1907, the [[International Anarchist Congress of
>   Amsterdam]] gathered delegates from 14 different countries, among
>   which important figures of the anarchist movement, including [[Errico
>   Malatesta]]

I want to remove the line that begins with `[[Image:" and closed by "observances]]`.
There could be several other lines of text that have brackets as well and I don't want to do a greedy search otherwise it may accidentally remove those other brackets too.

For example, if I just did a greedy `\\[\\[Image:.*\\]\\]`, I believe it will remove everything up to the last closing brackets (Ericco Malatesta)

Is there a regular expression that can make this easier for me?

Comment: Can you give an example of the inner brackets text that you're worried will be removed?

Comment: well, as you can see, if I just stopped at the first closing brackets I saw (end of Walter Crane), the regex would incorrectly remove the first part of the string.

Comment: what tool or language are you using for the regex?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133601

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
str.replaceAll("^\\[\\[([^\\[]*?(\\[\\[[^\\]]*\\]\\])?[^\\[]*?)*?\\]\\]\\s*", "");
```

Output from your input:

```
In 1907, the [[International...
```

This works because it's looking for matching pairs of `[[` and `]]` (and surrounding text) *inside* the first such pair.

Answer (score 2):

Lets see... what about using lazy repetition instead of greedy?

```
\[\[Image:.*?observances\]\]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, not every closing bracket will have the word "observances" occur just before it.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood. So you want to remove everything from [[Image up until it's respective closing ]]?? Impossible with regex, since you have an unknown number of nested  [[ ]] within. 

If you want a legit solution, you'll have to code it up yourself. If you use a stack, the algorithm is pretty straight forward. Just push a "[[" everytime you encounter a [[, and pop everytime you encounter a ]]. when the stack is empty, you've reached Image:'s closing tag.

Answer (score 0):

What's up with this example?

```js
s.replaceAll("(\\[{2}Image:(?:(?:\\[{2}).*\\]{2}|[^\\[])*\\]{2})", "");
```

Would replace this text only:

- `[[Image:ChicagoAnarchists.jpg|thumb|A sympathetic engraving by [[Walter Crane]] of the executed "Anarchists of Chicago" after the [[Haymarket affair]]. The Haymarket affair is generally considered the most significant event for the origin of international [[May Day]] observances]]`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this:

```
(.*?\\[\\[[^\\[]*?\\]\\][^\\[]*\\]\\])
```

I tried

```
public class My {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String foo = "[[Image:ChicagoAnarchists.jpg|thumb|A sympathetic engraving by [[Walter Crane]] of the executed \"Anarchists of Chicago\" after the [[Haymarket affair]]. The Haymarket affair is generally considered the most significant event for the origin of international [[May Day]] observances]] In 1907, the [[International Anarchist Congress of Amsterdam]] gathered delegates from 14 different countries, among which important figures of the anarchist movement, including [[Errico Malatesta]]";
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(.*?\\[\\[[^\\[]*?\\]\\][^\\[]*\\]\\])").matcher(foo);
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.print(m.group(1));
    }
}}
```

And it prints

```
[[Image:ChicagoAnarchists.jpg|thumb|A sympathetic engraving by [[Walter Crane]] of the executed "Anarchists of Chicago" after the [[Haymarket affair]]. The Haymarket affair is generally considered the most significant event for the origin of international [[May Day]] observances]]
```

Hope this helps :D

Answer (score 0):

Using the following test string (note, I added an additional `[[image:foobar[[foo [baz] bar]]foobar]]` in there):

```
[[Image:ChicagoAnarchists.jpg|thumb|A sympathetic engraving by [[Walter Crane]] of the executed \"Anarchists of Chicago\" after the [[Haymarket affair]]. The Haymarket affair is generally considered the most significant event for the origin of international [[May Day]] observances]] In 1907, the [[International Anarchist Congress of[[image:foobar[[foo [baz] bar]]foobar]] Amsterdam]] gathered delegates from 14 different countries, among which important figures of the anarchist movement, including [[Errico Malatesta]]
```

And a regular expression pattern of:

```
(?i)\\[\\[image:(?:\\[\\[(?:(?!(?:\\[\\[|]])).)*]]|(?:(?!(?:\\[\\[|]])).)*?)*?]]
```

`testString.replaceAll(<above pattern>, "")` will return:

```
 In 1907, the [[International Anarchist Congress of Amsterdam]] gathered delegates from 14 different countries, among which important figures of the anarchist movement, including [[Errico Malatesta]]
```

Here's a more detailed explanation of the regular expression:

```
(?i)                    # Case insensitive flag
\[\[image:              # Match literal characters '[[image:'
(?:                     # Begin non-capturing group
  \[\[                  # Match literal characters '[['
  (?:                   # Begin non-capturing group
    (?!                 # Begin non-capturing negative look-ahead group
      (?:               # Begin non-capturing group
        \[\[            # Match literal characters '[['
        |               # Match previous atom or next atom
        ]]              # Match literal characters ']]'
      )                 # End non-capturing group
    )                   # End non-capturing negative look-ahead group
    .                   # Match any character
  )                     # End non-capturing group
  *                     # Match previous atom zero or more times
  ]]                    # Match literal characters ']]'
  |                     # Match previous atom or next atom
  (?:                   # Begin non-capturing group
    (?!                 # Begin non-capturing negative look-ahead group
      (?:               # Begin non-capturing group
        \[\[            # Match literal characters '[['
        |               # Match previous atom or next atom
        ]]              # Match literal characters ']]'
      )                 # End non-capturing group
    )                   # End non-capturing negative look-ahead group
    .                   # Match any character
  )                     # End non-capturing group
  *?                    # Reluctantly match previous atom zero or more times
)                       # End non-capturing group
*?                      # Reluctantly match previous atom zero or more times
]]                      # Match literal characters ']]'
```

This will only handle one level of nested `[[...]]` patterns. As noted in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133601/can-regular-expressions-be-used-to-match-nested-patterns/133684#133684) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133601/can-regular-expressions-be-used-to-match-nested-patterns) that [TJR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/728/tjr) commented about above, regular expressions will not handle unlimited nested atoms. So this regular expression pattern will not match something like `[[foo[[baz]]bar]]` within a `[[image:...]]` string.

For a great regular expressions reference, see [Regular-Expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/).